# Select HTML Dropdown Box OPtions Using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, select, html-select

[Picture of Dropdown List Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/631fS.png)

I need to create a macro that selects a dropdown option from the list in the image.
I've tried using the below code, where NGR is defined as a string with values in the list.

```
With ie.Document
Set dropOptions = .getElementsByTagName("select")
For Each o In dropOptions.Options
    If o.Value = NGR Then
        o.Selected = True
    Exit For
End If
Next o
End With
```

I've also tried:

```
ie.Document.all.Item("ddlGrowerRegs").Value = NGR
```

and

```
ie.Document.getelementbyid("_ct10_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlGrowerRegs").Value = NGR
```

If anybody could tell me where I'm going wrong or how to select a dropdown value using the string NGR that would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when trying to select from a drop down. There is probably a 'change' event associated with the drop down. Try this after you change the drop down value.

```
ie.document.all.Item("_ct10_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd1GrowerRegs").Value = NRG
Dim htmldoc as HTMLDocument

Set ieEvent = htmldoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")

ieEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
ie.document.all.Item("_ct10_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd1GrowerRegs").dispatchEvent ieEvent
```

If that doesn't work then you can do this.

```
Ie.document.getElementByTagName ("option")(0).setAttribute ("selected") = "selected"
```